# How to extend C++ HTTP server with FastCGI applications?

Tags: php, c++, poco, fastcgi

I am writing a C++ HTTP server. But because developing in C++ is slower as for example in PHP I want to also support FastCGI applications (PHP via FastCGI, Python via FastCGI, etc.). So I want to use something similar to mod_fcgi (for Apache). Does someone know a good C++ FastCGI library (not for applications but for the webserver) ? I use the Poco library to write the webserver.

Another solution could be to use an PHP interpreter directly in my C++ server. Does anybody know some examples for this?

All solutions must have performance in mind.

Comment: Just curious, why are you writing an HTTP server?

Comment: @dgorton We need a high performance webserver (including a CMS system). Including our own version of analytics etc. But because developing is slower in C++ we want to do some parts in PHP (first, so when can replace them by C++ later).

Comment: apache, IIS, nginx, lighthttpd, mongoose, etc. all proved too slow?

Comment: A own server is faster when using a special virtual host system etc. So yes. But that is not the question...

Comment: SCGI it self is very easy to implement. But I didn't know that PHP does not support it :P So I probably need to implement FastCGI when I have time after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a FastCGI client, so I wrote it myself.
It was a lot of work, but i succeeded :)
It is a lot faster then plain old CGI (duh!).

Comment: it would be nice if you could add a link to the code or copy it here if possible.

Comment: Did you post it on github for instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a CMS system in C++, you should checkout [CppCMS web framework](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) in C++, its seems to be very fast.

If you are wanting to do it more from scratch and write the HTTP server, boost has some examples on how to setup an HTTP server [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

Now if you want to use CGI which is the slowest option, there is a [GNU Cdicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) library for handling CGI.

Comment: I already have a great HTTP server library (HTTPServer from Poco). But thanks anyway. And about GNU Cdicc, it seems this is for creating (Fast)CGI application and not for the webserver who uses this applications.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this topic yesterday. As you may know, fastcgi is built over tcp or unix socket waiting for a connection with a specific protocol.

The scheme of a request is the following: A client connects to the webserver, which connects to the fastcgi application.
Depending on the implementation (the specs says that the webserver gives a file descriptor connected to the webclient (the `accept()` sockfd) to the fastcgi applciation. I have not seen such a behaviour with nginx.

How can you experiment?

1. Install nginx (The configuration is very simple, see [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample))
2. Compile php (a simple ./configure --enable-fastcgi && make will do. Takes 30 seconds for me)
3. launch `php-cgi` on localhost port 9000 (`./sapi/cgi/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000`)
4. tcpdump / wireshark the output
5. Now stop php, and run a simple tcp server (for instance `nc -l 9000`)

I found [fcgi specification](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html) which is very usefull if you want to write your own library. I've not been (yet) able to find C/C++ code for a client to fcgi, but it can easily be found for perl.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at SCGI also. Because SCGI is a lot easier to implement as FastCGI. I let you all know what the result is.