# Does a PHP SAPI exist for Poco's HTTPServer?

Tags: php, c++, poco-libraries

For reasons outside of my control, I have the need to run files served by a Poco::HTTPServer through a PHP parser. Does a SAPI exist to allow this, or will one need to be written?

Comment: I'll mention it since you are getting nothing... seen this thread?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928012/how-to-extend-c-http-server-with-fastcgi-applications

Comment: I think this is the kind of question where if you can't find anything on Google, it's pretty safe to assume the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the answer is no.

However, it's not strictly necessary to implement a complete SAPI in order to run files through PHP. Depending on your requirements, it may be sufficient to run files through the PHP parser in CLI mode and pass the output back to the client. You could even make it [CGI-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) by simply setting a few environment variables for the CLI process.

Comment: It looks like a simple "No" is the best answer I'm going to get for this question, unfortunately. A complete SAPI will be required, as I will need to pass in full request data including $_GET, $_POST, etc.

Comment: PHP is designed to work through either a SAPI or CGI interface, so $_GET and $_POST should still be available assuming you implement your CGI interface correctly.

Comment: Can't believe how far off track I managed to get with this question. Cheers for helping me get things straight! All is working as expected now.